# Is there a tracking site for which community packages might need attention?

Tags: security

The question I'm referring to is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119274/does-ubuntu-generally-post-timely-security-updates/119278#119278).

While disabling everything but main and restricted is do-able to get for sure up to date packages...I think more people might jump in if there was a bug-need-squashing tracker that was more generally - package needs update for CVE-X.

This would be sort of like the FreeBSD `portaudit`

So the meat of the question: Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is want you want, but the [Advanced Search](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs?advanced=1) on bugs.launchpad.net lets you select "Show only bugs associated with a CVE" in the "Bug relationships" section.

Comment: Helpful, but not automated.  Still got an upvote.

Comment: Thanks again, this at least gives me something to start scripting with.