# Are all versions of Ubuntu secure against DROWN attack?

Tags: security, openssl

`OpenSSL` updates release versions [1.0.2g and 1.0.1s](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20160301.txt) to fix the DROWN vulnerability ([CVE-2016-0800](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-0800)). In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr, the latest `OpenSSL` version is [1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.18](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.18). Do I understand it correctly that DROWN fixes haven't been backported to Trusty? Are DROWN fixes needed to be incorporated to any Ubuntu versions?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2914-1/ all done.

Comment: @ArupRoyChowdhury that update is not mentioning CVE-2016-0800 but these:  CVE-2016-0702, CVE-2016-0705, CVE-2016-0797, CVE-2016-0798, CVE-2016-0799

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell if a CVE has been fixed in Ubuntu's repositories?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/563408/how-can-i-tell-if-a-cve-has-been-fixed-in-ubuntus-repositories)

Comment: DROWN is an old issue - affects SSLv2.  SSLv2 is disabled in Ubuntu OpenSSL.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[CVE-2016-0800](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-0800.html):

> **Priority Medium**
>
> **Description**
>
> The SSLv2 protocol, as used in OpenSSL before 1.0.1s and 1.0.2 before
> 1.0.2g and other products, requires a server to send a ServerVerify message
> before establishing that a client possesses certain plaintext RSA data,
> which makes it easier for remote attackers to decrypt TLS ciphertext data
> by leveraging a Bleichenbacher RSA padding oracle, aka a "DROWN" attack.

```
Package
Source: openssl098 (LP Ubuntu Debian)
Upstream:   needs-triage
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin):    not-affected
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr): not-affected
Ubuntu Touch 15.04: DNE
Ubuntu Core 15.04:  DNE
Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily Werewolf):   DNE
Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus):    DNE

Package
Source: openssl (LP Ubuntu Debian)
Upstream:   needs-triage
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin):    not-affected
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr): not-affected
Ubuntu Touch 15.04: not-affected
Ubuntu Core 15.04:  not-affected
Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily Werewolf):   not-affected
Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus):    not-affected
```

---

- DNE = does not exist
- Ubuntu is not affected by this problem.