# Is the latest zero-day exploit (CVE-2021-41773) fixed in fully patched Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS?

Tags: server, apache2, security

I never understood how Ubuntu manages Apache versions, so the question: **is Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS vulnerable to the CVE-2021-41773 (a path traversal attack to map URLs to files outside the expected document root)?**
More info on the vulnerability:

- https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html
- https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-41773

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell if a CVE has been fixed in Ubuntu's repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563408/how-can-i-tell-if-a-cve-has-been-fixed-in-ubuntus-repositories)

Comment: @Bruni, no it does not. If I search https://ubuntu.com/security/cve?q=CVE-2021-41773 it returns 0 results. Also, as I understand, the vulnerability exists only in Apache 2.4.49, but not in 2.4.50 or 2.4.48, but Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS shows Apache/2.4.41 no matter how many updates it has installed. So it may be vulnerable if they have merged changes from the v2.4.49. Or am I wrong?

Comment: only security patches  from later versions are patched (if any).

Comment: @MarisB. It's second in the list in https://ubuntu.com/security/cve?q=&package=apache2 and all releases are marked as "Not vulnerable"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 is reported to be not vulnerable:

https://ubuntu.com/security/cve-2021-41773

This is also true for 20.04.03