# Vulnerabilities in Bind9

Tags: server, dns, bind, vulnerability

I have received below vulnerabilities advisory in my ubuntu 20 servers installed with bind9. existing version is - **BIND 9.16.1-Ubuntu (Stable Release)** and upgrade it to the latest. latest bind9 in ubuntu 20 is the same. Any thoughts and updates ?

| CVE ID | Vulnerability Name | Affected Products |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CVE-2021-25220 | DNS forwarders - cache poisoning vulnerability | BIND 9.11.0 -> 9.11.36; 9.12.0 -> 9.16.26; 9.17.0 -> 9.18.0; BIND Supported Preview Editions: 9.11.4-S1 -> 9.11.36-S1 9.16.8-S1 -> 9.16.26-S1 |
| CVE-2022-0396 | DoS from specifically crafted TCP packets | BIND 9.16.11 -> 9.16.26, 9.17.0 -> 9.18.0 and versions 9.16.11-S1 -> 9.16.26-S1 of the BIND Supported Preview Edition |
| CVE-2022-0635 | DNAME insist with synth-from-dnssec enabled | BIND 9.18.0 |
| CVE-2022-0667 | Assertion failure on delayed DS lookup | BIND 9.18.0 |

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  So this is a Ubuntu Core 20 Server and not a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server?

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/security/cve-2021-25220

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell if a CVE has been fixed in Ubuntu's repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563408/how-can-i-tell-if-a-cve-has-been-fixed-in-ubuntus-repositories)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When speaking about vulnerabilities and asking questions, it's incredibly important that you be specific when referring to versions of software, like you are with BIND and the CVEs. There is no "Ubuntu 20". There is "Ubuntu Server 20.04", "Ubuntu Desktop 20.04", "Ubuntu Core 20", and "Ubuntu Server 20.10".

With regards to the status of updates, you can always follow these via [the CVE page on the Ubuntu Security website](https://ubuntu.com/security/cves).

With regards to your specific questions for the 20.04 versions:

| CVE | TL;DR |
| --- | --- |
| [CVE-2021-25220](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-25220) | Resolved (As of March 16, 2022) |
| [CVE-2022-0396](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-0396) | Not Vulnerable (Only affects 9.16.11 or higher) |
| [CVE-2022-0635](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-0635) | Not Vulnerable (Only affects 9.18.0) |
| [CVE-2022-0667](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-0667) | Not Vulnerable (Only affects 9.18.0) |

Comment: Thanks for the update matigo. Yes i was not updated all the version, it is "Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS".