# CVE-2021-38297 / GO Vulnerability

Tags: snap, vulnerability

We have (server environment) go vulnerability on some instances. And source for this vulnerability look like **snapd** . Do you have any solution for it ?

/snap/snapd/16292/usr/lib/snapd/snapd

go1.13.8 current version  / should be  1.17.2 or 1.16.9

Go before 1.16.9 and 1.17.x before 1.17.2 has a Buffer Overflow via large arguments in a function invocation from a WASM module, when GOARCH=wasm GOOS=js is used.

Thank you.Regards

Comment: It is unclear what system you are using and why you didn't update snap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell if a CVE has been fixed in Ubuntu's repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563408/how-can-i-tell-if-a-cve-has-been-fixed-in-ubuntus-repositories)

Comment: @muru It is different because it is about a snap package.

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't think it makes a difference in this case. The vulnerability exists for a particular build configuration, which is not used on Ubuntu snap or no snap. (Even snap runtimes are based on Ubuntu)

Comment: @muru thank you for the explanation.  Exactly snapd is look like up to date.                                  
snap refresh
All snaps up to date.

Answer (score 3):

The current `go` version in Ubuntu snap is `1.18.5`.

It is unclear who "we" have the 1.13.8 version.

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ snap info go
name:      go
summary:   Go programming language compiler, linker, stdlib
publisher: Michael Hudson-Doyle (mwhudson)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/go
contact:   michael.hudson@ubuntu.com
license:   BSD-3-Clause
description: |
  This snap provides an assembler, compiler, linker, and compiled libraries
  for the Go programming language.
snap-id: Md1HBASHzP4i0bniScAjXGnOII9cEK6e
channels:
  latest/stable:    1.18.5           2022-08-11 (9952) 104MB classic
```

Comment: snapd have a go version 13.8.

Comment: So run `snap refresh`

Comment: name:      go
summary:   Go programming language compiler, linker, stdlib
publisher: Michael Hudson-Doyle (mwhudson)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/go
contact:   michael.hudson@ubuntu.com
license:   BSD-3-Clause
description: |
This snap provides an assembler, compiler, linker, and compiled libraries for the Go programming language.    // no go from ubuntu server go it is coming with snapd service