CVE-2023-48795 - Openssh
I see that Ubuntu CVE/Security advisories only mention the source package name (openssh) and not the package name (openssh-server)
case in point:
CVE-2023-48795 which affects openssh sftp server but Ubuntu CVE/Security advisories report only openssh.
How do i search if openssh sftpserver 1:8.9p1-ubuntu0.3 is impacted ?
https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2023-48795
(shows only openssh and not opensshsftpserver)
Thanks
Inder

apt info openssh-sftp-server reveals: the source for openssh-sftp-serve is openssh. According to your link it seems to be fixed

This question is similar to: How can I tell if a CVE has been fixed in Ubuntu's repositories?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Check the changelog of whichever package you're in to see if it has a fix: https://askubuntu.com/a/830911/158442
